# Did something break with beautifulsoup element extraction?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Classic case of `code used to work, changed nothing, now it doesn't work no more` here. I'm trying to extract a list of unique appid values [from this page](https://view-source:https://steamdb.info/tag/1716/) that I'm saving locally as `roguelike.html`

The code I have looks like this and it used to work as of a couple months ago when I last ran it, but now the end result is a list of 1 with just a `NoneType` in it. Any ideas as to what's going wrong here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text_file = open("roguelike.html", "rb")
steamdb_text = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(steamdb_text, "html.parser")

trs = [tr for tr in soup.find_all('tr')]

apps = []

for app in soup.find_all('tr'):
    apps.append(app.get('data-appid'))
appset = list(set(apps))
```

Is there a simpler way to get the unique appids from the page source? The individual elements I'm trying to cycle over and grab look like:

```
<tr class="app" data-appid="98821" data-cache="1533726913">
```

where I want all the unique `data-appid` values. I'm scratching my head trying to figure out if formatting in the page changed (doesn't seem like it), or some kind of version upgrade in Spyder, Python, or Beautifulsoup broke something that used to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked well for me.  You should make sure that the html file you have is the right file.  Perhaps you've hit a capcha test in the html test.

Comment: Ah I think I see the issue. What I did today was download the page by going view source -> save as. I think that method generates a different html base than by loading the page in browser then doing save as from there. Doing it from the browser without doing the view source got the results I was looking for.

Comment: @AI52487963  Yes, when you do a browser save page, there is usually a drop down on the lower right, that defaults to save all assets, not just the html file.  You can change the dropdown to "Webpage, HTML only" which is a lot simpler then the view-source cut-n-paste method.   Although I use 'curl -O' which is even simpler....